# Why can't I edit formatting after a VBA process has set it?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have some code to set formatting for a sheet (see below).

But once the formatting has been set, users can't then change it after the fact.

The formatting is applied as part of a business process to standardise look and feel and make it ready for reporting, but during the reporting review, reviewers may change content and practice is to highlight the cell yellow (or make font red) to indicate where they have made a change.

It seems that they can now do neither, because my code set cell colour and font colour.

Any ideas on how to make this editable again, after the code has executed?

Thanks

```
Sub FormatCCO()

'Turn off pop-up alerts which are caused by having moved many WIP sheets over with the same dropdown list names
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Turn off screen updating for smoother look and feel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
'Delete the sheet "CCO Formatted" if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CCO Formatted").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

'Create a copy of the Combined sheet and rename it CCO Formatted, placing it in 2nd tab position
    Sheets("Combined").Select
    Sheets("Combined").Copy Before:=Sheets(2)
    Sheets("Combined (2)").Select
    Sheets("Combined (2)").Name = "CCO Formatted"

'Delete all columns not required for CCO reporting (including last rows with the Peoplesoft Tiers
    Sheets("CCO Formatted").Range("A:A, F:F, O:O, P:P, S:U, W:Y, AC:AC, AH:AJ, AL:AT, AY:BF").EntireColumn.Delete

'Move status to Column E (after Allegation but before Date Opened)
    Columns("i:i").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("e:e").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

'Format rows 2:350 - remove cell colouring, turn text to verdana 9pt black
    Rows("2:350").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.font
        .Name = "Verdana"
        .Size = 9
        .bold = False
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

' Centre (horizontally and vertically) all columns, then only left align Allegation (c), Key Factors (i) Investigation status (j). Autofit height
Range("a:aa").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("a:aa").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Rows("2:350").AutoFit
Range("C:C,I:I,J:J").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

'Re-bold header row and Days Open column
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.font.bold = True
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.font.bold = True

'Sort by [Date Opened]
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    End If
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CCO Formatted").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CCO Formatted").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
        :=Range("f1:f350"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CCO Formatted").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
'Apply conditional formatting to [Raised Profile] Cases
    Range("A2:G350,I2:AA350").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$r2=""Yes"""
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(255, 220, 185)
    End With
     With Selection.FormatConditions(1).font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

'Apply conditional formatting to cases where [Status] is 'Closed'
    Range("A2:G350,I2:AA350").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$E2=""CLOSED"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
     With Selection.FormatConditions(1).font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

'Break external links (from migrating from WIP backups)
Call BreakExternalLinks

' Reset borders from A1 across to the last row and column
Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long

    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lngLstCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For Each rngCell In Range(Range("a1"), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol))
        If rngCell.Value > "" Then
            rngCell.Select 'Select cells
            With Selection.Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    Next

'Return cursor to cell A1
Application.GoTo Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Check Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Conditional formatting overwrittes the normal formatting, so if you need someone else to change the cells, you need to get ride of it.

Comment: Hi @xwhitelight and Damian, there are two places where I apply conditional formatting:
'Apply conditional formatting to [Raised Profile] Cases
'Apply conditional formatting to cases where [Status] is 'Closed'

And whilst the code searches across the whole range down to row 350, only a handful of cases meet the criteria and have the conditional formatting applied.

The problem is, I am blocked from editing any cell (even those without conditional formatting) - I cant change font, border, fill colour - presumably because the other pieces of VBA code set them?

Comment: @Damian - see above - I'm blocked even on the cells which have no conditional formatting applied...

Comment: @Ollie_Australia As far as I can see, only your column H has no conditional formatting, the rest all have it from row 2 to row 350.